# Do Eclipse need to install all APIs to see the benefits of different APIs

Tags: android, api, sdk, android-virtual-device

"Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Google APIs"

Will this mean that I need to download all APIs in sdk so that the AVD can play all applications sourced from different APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note : Downloading Higher API level SDK doesn't include Lower level SDKs**

For Different API level testing you need to download Different SDK for Different Levles...
but in your case..

If you have already downloaded API 19 SDK you  just have to select API Plateform for your project from project property..

For that.. `Right Click on your Project->Properties->select Android->Select Android 4.4.2 (API 19 plateform)`  and then click on OK...

hope this helps..

Comment: If you haven't downloaded Android 4.4.2 (API 19 plateform) download it from SDK manager and select it from project property...